# How to access iter_size variable in Python (Caffe)?

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe

I am trying to read the parameters of the `solver.prototxt` file in Python. I can see variables like `iter`, `max_iter`, `display` etc. using `solver.iter`, `solver.param.max_iter` etc. however, I cannot access the `iter_size` parameter which performs multiple iterations of forward/backward before updating the weights

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like `iter_size` is not exposed to [pycaffe interface](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/python/caffe/_caffe.cpp#L443-L446):

```
bp::class_<SolverParameter>("SolverParameter", bp::no_init)
    .add_property("max_iter", &SolverParameter::max_iter)
    .add_property("display", &SolverParameter::display)
    .add_property("layer_wise_reduce", &SolverParameter::layer_wise_reduce);
```

As you can see `max_iter` and `display` are exposed, but not `iter_size`.
I suppose adding a line

```
    .add_property("iter_size", &SolverParameter::iter_size)
```

After the `"display"` line should do the trick.
Remember to compile the pycaffe interface after this change with `make pycaffe`.